# HTML5 Video/Audio to Nodejs via Socket.io but with a twist - FFMPEG

Tags: html, node.js, express, ffmpeg, socket.io

I'm writing this very simple "skype clone". I tried a variety of other languages, python and layering over Node.js with Meteor, WebRTC, but Node.js+socket.io seems to be working the best and cleanest however I've hit a road block and I can't get it all to work correctly.

I have two issues, 
1. I think I'm sending real data from the HTML5 getUserMedia, but I might not, and I don't know how to test or find out. I think that using, "video.src = window.URL.createObjectURL(stream);" makes the Blob stream an actual Data stream... but I don't know.

This is my Broadcast.html 
It's a very simple getUserMedia grab the camera and microphone... Then I connect to the Socket and on click of the Broadcast button, fires off the Emit to 'Join' and sends over the 'webcamstream' data.

```
<video autoplay height="280"></video>
<button class="recordbutton" onclick="startBroadcasting();">Broadcast</button>


<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
var socket = io.connect('http://video.domain.com:3031');
socket.on('connect', function() {
  $('#conversation').append('Connected <br />');
});

function onVideoFail(e) {
  console.log('webcam fail!', e);
};

function hasGetUserMedia() {
  return !!(navigator.getUserMedia || 
    navigator.webkitGetUserMedia || 
    navigator.mozGetUserMedia || 
    navigator.msGetUserMedia);
}

if (hasGetUserMedia()) {
  alert('It is working...');
} else {
  alert('getUserMedia() is not supported in your browser');
}

window.URL = window.URL || window.webkitURL;
navigator.getUserMedia  = navigator.getUserMedia || 
                         navigator.webkitGetUserMedia ||
                          navigator.mozGetUserMedia || 
                           navigator.msGetUserMedia;

var video = document.querySelector('video');
var streamRecorder;
var webcamstream;

if (navigator.getUserMedia) {
        navigator.getUserMedia({audio: true, video: true}, function(stream) {
            video.src = window.URL.createObjectURL(stream);
            webcamstream = stream;
        }, onVideoFail);
} else {
   alert ('failed');
}

function startBroadcasting() {
    alert('Broadcast Now Clicked');
    console.log(webcamstream);
    socket.emit('join', webcamstream);
    socket.emit('echo', 'echo1 echo2 echo3 <br />');
}

socket.on('echo', function(data) {
    $('#conversation').append(data);
});
```

This is the app.js
2. What I'm trying to do here is consume in the 'stream' from the socket, but in it's place I have a test video to see if the FFMPEG is actually working. I'm using https://github.com/schaermu/node-fluent-ffmpeg.

When I run this test with my myth.mp4 file, I do get an out.avi however it's 0 bytes ??

```
var express = require('express');
var socket = require('socket.io');
var ffmpeg = require('fluent-ffmpeg');
var fs = require('fs');

var app = express();

app.configure(function(req, res){
    app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/'));
});

var server = app.listen(3031);
var io = socket.listen(server);

io.sockets.on('connection', function(socket) {
    socket.on('join', function(stream) {
        socket.stream = stream;
        socket.emit('echo', socket.stream + '<br />');
        var proc = new ffmpeg({source:'/srv/www/domain.com/video/red/myth.mp4'})
            .withAspect('4:3')
            .withSize('640x480')
            .applyAutopadding(true, 'white')
            .saveToFile('/srv/www/domain.com/video/red/out.avi', function(retcode, error){
                socket.emit('echo', 'file has been converted succesfully <br />');
            });
    });
    socket.on('echo', function(data) {
        socket.emit('echo', data);
    });
});
```

I get no errors on Node Start up, I get no Errors on running.  I do get a 0 Byte out.avi file freshly created every time I run this.

I have a linode VPS with CentOS/Nginx

node -v
v0.10.21

FFMPEG
ffmpeg version 1.2 Copyright (c) 2000-2013 the FFmpeg developers
  built on Nov 23 2013 17:43:13 with gcc 4.4.7 (GCC) 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-3)
  configuration: --enable-version3 --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libvpx --enable-libfaac --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libtheora --enable-libvorbis --enable-libx264 --enable-libvo-aacenc --enable-libxvid --disable-ffplay --enable-shared --enable-gpl --enable-postproc --enable-nonfree --enable-avfilter --enable-pthreads --extra-cflags=-fPIC
  libavutil      52. 18.100 / 52. 18.100
  libavcodec     54. 92.100 / 54. 92.100
  libavformat    54. 63.104 / 54. 63.104
  libavdevice    54.  3.103 / 54.  3.103
  libavfilter     3. 42.103 /  3. 42.103
  libswscale      2.  2.100 /  2.  2.100
  libswresample   0. 17.102 /  0. 17.102
  libpostproc    52.  2.100 / 52.  2.100
Hyper fast Audio and Video encoder
usage: ffmpeg [options] [[infile options] -i infile]... {[outfile options] outfile}...

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Does the client get the `'echo'`?

Comment: Yes, my socket.on('echo') ... Work fine.

Comment: Then have you figured out the `retcode`?

Comment: I have not, is that what i'm failing to do?  I don't really know what retcode is or does!?!

Comment: It's probably some stdout from the ffmpeg process. While you're at it, you should check the `error` as well. One of them might contain some valuable information you're missing out one.

Comment: Change that line to something like this?  .saveToFile('/path/to/your_target.avi', function(stdout, stderr) {

Comment: Yes and then `console.log()` it to the node prompt and update your question with that.

Comment: here is the log....  eeeek  ;(  <br />  ffmpeg version 1.2 Copyright (c) 2000-2013 the FFmpeg developers built on Nov 23 2013 17:43:13 with gcc 4.4.7 (GCC) 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-3) configuration: --enable-version3 --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libvpx --enable-libfaac --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libtheora --enable-libvorbis --enable-libx264 --enable-libvo-aacenc --enable-libxvid --disable-ffplay --enable-shared --enable-gpl --enable-

Comment: postproc --enable-nonfree --enable-avfilter --enable-pthreads --extra-cflags=-fPIC libavutil 52. 18.100 / 52. 18.100 libavcodec 54. 92.100 / 54. 92.100 libavformat 54. 63.104 / 54. 63.104 libavdevice 54. 3.103 / 54. 3.103 libavfilter 3. 42.103 / 3. 42.103 libswscale 2. 2.100 / 2. 2.100 libswresample 0. 17.102 / 0. 17.102 libpostproc 52. 2.100 / 52. 2.100 Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from

Comment: '/srv/www/domain.com/video/red/myth.mp4': Metadata: major_brand : isom minor_version : 1 compatible_brands: isomavc1 creation_time : 2014-01-05 03:42:36 Duration: 00:52:09.99, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 1084 kb/s Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 720x404, 946 kb/s, 29.97 fps, 29.97 tbr, 120k tbn, 59.94 tbc Metadata: creation_time : 2014-01-05 03:42:36 Stream #0:1(und): Audio: aac (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 133 kb/s Metadata:

Comment: and the important bits....  creation_time : 2014-01-05 03:42:43 handler_name : GPAC ISO Audio Handler [Parsed_pad_0 @ 0xc93400] Input area 0:60:720:464 not within the padded area 0:0:640:480 or zero-sized [graph 0 input from stream 0:0 @ 0xc93820] Failed to configure input pad on Parsed_pad_0 Error opening filters!

Comment: I removed .applyAutopadding(true, 'white') and it converted the test video!   I should remember to read my built in error messages :(

Comment: @SimonPlus  If I may, doing research I've found that some example code head explicitly set headers, ie.  Keep-alive and upgrade?   Doing this streaming stuff do I need to set headers like that here in this app.jsfile or in my nginx conf?   The video didn't actually fully recode into an .avi, i got a Time out?

Comment: You should have edited your answer with that output instead of posting it all in the comments.